# Excel VBA: data member not found

Tags: excel, vba, compiler-errors

This question is related to the VBA compile error "Method or Data Member not found". I have looked for the answer to my question in many of similar questions with this title but I did not actually find it.

I have a worksheet object declared like this

```
Dim wDef As Worksheet
```

Then I set it this way:

```
Set wDef = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Deformata")
```

In the worksheet there is a check box named CheckBox2.
If I try to assign it a value by using this code:

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Deformata").CheckBox2.Value = True
```

the statement succeed. However if I used the previously set object it fails; the code is the following one:

```
wDef.CheckBox2.Value = True
```

Can anybody explain why in one case the statement is correctly executed and in the other it gives out the error shown here below?

[image]

I am not a magician in VBA, but shouldn't be ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Deformata") and wDef exactly the same object?

Comment: Side note: try `Dim wDef As Object` :-)

Comment: If you do want to use `Dim wDef As Worksheet`, then below code works well. 

`wDef.Shapes("CheckBox2").OLEFormat.Object.Object.Value = True`

Comment: When you add controls to a worksheet it's like you're creating a specific "subclass" of the out-of-the-box `Worksheet` object: adding properties/methods that a regular worksheet doesn't have.   A regular worksheet doesn't have (eg) a member named `CheckBox2` so you get a compile-time error when VBA tries to resolve `ws.CheckBox2` (hence that error message)   If - as BigBen suggests - you use `As Object` then that type is generic enough for VBA not to run a *compile-time* check against `CheckBox2`, it can be resolved at *run-time*.  Like early binding vs. late binding.

Comment: It depends on that the Checkbox is an ActiveX or a Forms object. If ActiveX then it can be reached through the object variable assigned to the sheet. `Don't define with Dim statement.`

Comment: Thanks to everyone for valuable comments.
@TimWilliams Why do you say in your answer that "Perhaps the best approach here is to give your worksheet a specific codename" rather than defining a variable? Both approaches seem to work fine.

Comment: Setting the code name and just using that means you don't need to declare or set a worksheet variable, and your code is protected against users changing the tab name.

Answer (score 5):

When you add [ActiveX] controls to a worksheet, or if you add code to the worksheet code module, it's like you're creating a specific "subclass" of the out-of-the-box `Worksheet` object: adding properties/methods that a regular worksheet doesn't have.

A regular worksheet doesn't have (eg) a member named `CheckBox2` so you get a compile-time error when VBA tries to resolve `ws.CheckBox2` (hence that error message)

If - as BigBen suggests - you use `As Object` when declaring `ws` then that type is generic enough for VBA not to run a compile-time check against `CheckBox2`, it can be resolved at run-time. Like early binding vs. late binding.

`ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Deformata")` is resolved at run-time, so that also doesn't give you the error.

Perhaps the best approach here is to give your worksheet a specific codename (distinct from the Tab name) so you can refer to it directly using that codename, without having to declare it as a variable. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.codename